# How to combine awk and sed in while read line from text file to pull parts and rearrange the output

Tags: bash, python-2.7, awk, sed

I have text files that have a `source path + filename` and the `destination path`.

What I need is to pull the `destination path` then add just the `filename` from the line then add a system `command` to it.

I am nesting a `while` loop within a `for` loop to crawl through a directory of text files to first stage files then get the hash using digest then write the results to a text file.

Each line in the text file looks like this.

```
/folder/folder/folder/file.jpg       /folder/folder/folder/xxxxx/
```

I can get the destination path or the file name but it is giving me fits trying to get them together.
I need it to combine into `/folder/folder/folder/xxxxx/file.jpg`.

Then I need to add a stage command, `stage /folder/folder/folder/xxxxx/file.jpg`

this gets path;

```
for file in ls 10*.txt; do cat $file | awk '{print $2}'; done
```

And this gets the file name;

```
for file in ls 10*.txt; do TIF=`cat $file | awk '{print $6}' FS=/`; echo $TIF; done
```

But when I try to combine them using `awk`, `sed`, `cut` or anything esle I can Google, it only pulls the first one in the statement.

Comment: are there spaces or other none alpha-numeric chars in any of your paths or filenames? Is there a space or a tab char separating the two files? Please update the body of your question (Q) with this important information. DO NOT reply in the comments, please!

Comment: `for file in ls 10*.txt;` should be without `ls`: `for file in 10*.txt;`. When you don't have a file called `ls`, you see no difference. Calling `ls` for the file listing is not needed (and not good), but would be `for file in $(ls 10*.txt);` Not good parsing output of `ls`.

Comment: Even if there are 50+ text files?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your input file has tab separated fields and there are no space chars in any of your file/path data, try this,

```
echo "/folder/folder/folder/file.jpg    /folder/folder/folder/xxxxx/" \
| awk '-F\t' '{n=split($1,fileArr,"/"); print "stage " $2 fileArr[n]}'
```

**output**

```
stage /folder/folder/folder/xxxxx/file.jpg
```

This will then work with

```
awk '-F\t' '{n=split($1,fileArr,"/"); print "stage " $2 fileArr[n]}' file
```

Review the output to be sure all files will be processed correctly. If so, you can then pass the output to `bash` and all files will be processed (`stage`d?), i.e.

```
awk '-F\t' '{n=split($1,fileArr,"/"); print "stage " $2 fileArr[n]}' file | bash
```

IHTH

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` with the delimiter `#`.
First match the last word (string without slash) before the whitespace, it will be stored in `\1`.
Store the path (after the whitespace) in `\2`.

```
echo '/folder/folder/folder/file.jpg       /folder/folder/folder/xxxxx/' |
   sed -r 's#.*/([^/]*)\s+(.*)#stage \2/\1#'
```